# How to Create a Visual that Allows a Column to Decompose with itself

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a text column, "KPI", with up to 19 different options, another text column, "ID" and a date column.  I can easily find the count of each KPI per date; however, I need to decompose the KPI options into other selections that a similar ID may have had within the same date.

For example, for KPI "Rework" that has a count of 62 on 2/19/2024, I need to identify how many of those 62 also have a KPI "Booking Confirmation" or "Loading Issues" within the same ID on that date.

I thought of using a decomposing tree first, but it won't allow you to decompose a column with itself.  Also thought of a solution where KPI is on the x-axis of a stacked column and each category is sub-divided into its other components; however, I can't figure a solution to make that work.

The decomposing tree visual would be preferred if there is a way to get it to work, but my creativity has been exhausted at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table that groups your data by ID and Date, then filters by the KPIs of interest. For each group (ID and Date), check if there are multiple KPI entries of interest ("Rework", "Booking Confirmation", "Loading Issues")
and then you can  use this measure :

```
Rework_With_Other_KPIs = 
VAR ReworkDate = SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[Date])
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        COUNTROWS('Table'),
        FILTER(
            ALLEXCEPT('Table', 'Table'[ID], 'Table'[Date]),
            'Table'[Date] = ReworkDate &&
            'Table'[KPI] = "Rework" &&
            'Table'[ID] IN (
                SELECTCOLUMNS(
                    FILTER(
                        'Table',
                        'Table'[Date] = ReworkDate &&
                        ('Table'[KPI] = "Booking Confirmation" || 'Table'[KPI] = "Loading Issues")
                    ),
                    "ID", 'Table'[ID]
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

You store the selected date to focus on and with ALLEXCEPT it will retain the context of the current ID and Date while removing filters from other columns.
It checks for rows where the KPI is "Rework" for the same ID on the same date as those having either "Booking Confirmation" or "Loading Issues".
COUNTROWS counts the number of rows that meet the criteria.

Comment: That's a good way to identify how many IDs per date have KPI = "Rework" AND a secondary KPI; however, what I'm really after is being able to identify how many IDs have any given KPI, then of THOSE IDs, how many have another KPI, then further decompose it for a third KPI set, etc.

For example, the result would show that there were 62 IDs with KPI = "Rework", then of those 62, 12 also had KPI = "Booking Confirmation", 30 also had KPI = "Loading Issue", and 20 didn't have another KPI.  Then maybe of the 30 that had KPI = "Loading Issue", 6 also had the KPI "Booking Confirmation", etc.

Comment: And all of those selections need to be dynamic as well.  In other words, I'm not just interested in "Rework" as a primary KPI followed by "Booking Confirmation" or "Loading Issue" as a secondary KPI, but primary KPI could be any of 19 different KPIs, and an ID could have any combination of those 19.